# PHP not echoing HTML when showing search results

Tags: php, html, mysql

When submitting a search, I am trying to echo certain html in the page body but all I am getting is the page without the html echo'd and I can't see the issue.

```
function search($lname,$postcode){

    $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lname=:lname AND postcode=:postcode");
    $stmt->execute(array(':lname'=>$lname, ':postcode'=>$postcode));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} 

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $result = search($lname, $postcode);
    if ($result['rating'] == 'good') {
        $user->redirect('./results.php?good');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No one will check all these codes. Do debug and find problem part.

Comment: Narrowed it down but is now producing no errors, always loading ?notfound even when details are correct and in db

Comment: The search function isnt being used in the code you are showing..

Comment: `$search = $_GET['rating'];` is a string here. It defiinitely has no `rating` key. Did you forget to call `search` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can hardly tell what your `search` function is used to but the errors are:

1. you don't call for `search` function in a provided code.
   I suppose it should be called something like

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['search'])){
       $lname = $_POST['lname'];
       $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
       $result = search($lname, $postcode);   // or maybe this->search
   ```
2. next you want to check `rating` key of something. I can't understand of what. What is `$_GET['rating'];`? Sure it's some string variable, if it is - it has no key `rating`. Then I suppose you want to check `rating` key of a result, returned by `search` function?
   It can be done like:

   ```
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
   $result = search($lname, $postcode);   // or maybe this->search
   if ($result['rating'] == 'good') { /* do something */ }
   ```

But that's not all. As in your current implementation `search` returns `bool`, there's no `rating` key in `$result` obviously. So, I suppose you should return `$userRow` and check for `rating` key in it:

```
function search($lname,$postcode){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lname=:lname AND postcode=:postcode");
    $stmt->execute(array(':lname'=>$lname, ':postcode'=>$postcode));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($userRow);  // for test purposes
    return $userRow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was implementing the search call before but will go back to trying as these keep throwing `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/galllwjo/public_html/Customer/ClientCheck/clients/search.php on line 27`  I will edit my post when done.

Comment: Any ideas, I tried to get yours working but kept with same error.  Post edited

Comment: ANd what is on line 27? Are you sure that error is connected with search method?

Comment: Possible to live chat, going away from structured help topic here

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
   $postcode = trim($_POST['postcode']);  

   if($lname==""){
      $error[] = "Provide Last Name."; 
   }else if($postcode==""){
      $error[] = "Provide Postcode.";
   }else{
       try{
           $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE lname=:lname AND postcode=:postcode");
           $stmt->execute(array(":lname"=>$lname, ":postcode"=>$postcode));
           $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

           if($userRow['rating'] == ''){
               $user->redirect('./results.php?notfound');
           }else{
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'good'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?good');
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'caution'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?caution');
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'badnopay'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?badnopay');
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'badabusive'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?badabusive');
               }
               if($userRow['rating'] == 'badlate'){
                   $user->redirect('./results.php?badlate');
               }
           }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```